# Why Google BigQuery always shows different results when using EXTRACT MONTH and GROUP BY?

Tags: google-bigquery

Why do queries in BigQuery like below, with EXTRACT MONTH and GROUP BY, show different results?

First, query to show the count in Jan 2022 (1 month):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(start_station_name) AS num_rides, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date) AS month
FROM `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire`
WHERE start_station_name='Hyde Park Corner, Hyde Park' AND start_date >= '2022-01-01' and start_date <= '2022-01-31'
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month;
```

Result:

[query1-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N6NP.png)

Second, query to show the count in Jan & Feb 2022 (2 months):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(start_station_name) AS num_rides, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date) AS month
FROM `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire`
WHERE start_station_name='Hyde Park Corner, Hyde Park' AND start_date >= '2022-01-01' and start_date <= '2022-02-28'
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month;
```

Result:

[query2-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X74yj.png)

The count in January is now larger than in the 1st query.

Third, query to show the count in Jan, Feb, and March 2022 (3 months):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(start_station_name) AS num_rides, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date) AS month
FROM `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire`
WHERE start_station_name='Hyde Park Corner, Hyde Park' AND start_date >= '2022-01-01' and start_date <= '2022-03-31'
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month;
```

Result:

[query3-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8J44.png)

The count in February is now larger than in the previous query.

And so on. If I add more months, the count in the previous month will be larger.

Anyone can explain? Or I missed some operators in the queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are excluding last day of a month from a query. The correct where statements are:

- first query: start_date >= '2022-01-01' and start_date < '2022-02-01'
- second quer: start_date >= '2022-01-01' and start_date < '2022-03-01'
- third query: start_date >= '2022-01-01' and start_date < '2022-04-01'

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I found the error. Yes, I ignore the time so I exclude the last day of the month. But the query should be start_date >= '2022-01-01' and start_date < '2022-02-01' (first query), because the equal sign will include day in February.

Comment: You are right. I have updated the answer and replaced the "<=" with "<" sign. Personally I prefer
 - start_date < '2022-04-01' instead of
 - start_date <= '2022-03-31 23:59:59'

Yes, you do show explicitly that there is time in the datetime column. But there can also be milliseconds that are excluded from the filter much like you excluded time from the datetime earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for suggestion. I have fixed the error. Yes, I ignore the time, so I exclude the last day of the month.

After including the time in query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(start_station_name) AS num_rides, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date) AS month
FROM `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire`
WHERE start_station_name='Hyde Park Corner, Hyde Park' AND start_date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00' and start_date <= '2022-03-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month;
```

there is no difference in results anymore.